# Quick way to use the row element as name and the value as column in R

Tags: r

I do this with some steps that are not at all elegant and safe, but I'm sure that there is a way more easily and fast.
I need a help to know what is a quick way to go from dataframe_1 to dataframe_2.

```
#from this
a<-c("A","A","B","B","C","C")
b<-c(1,2,12,2,4,5)
dataframe_1<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)
  a  b
1 A  1
2 A  2
3 B 12
4 B  2
5 C  4
6 C  5

#to this
a<-c(1,2)
b<-c(12,2)
c<-c(4,5)
dataframe_2<-cbind.data.frame(A=a,B=b,C=c)
  A  B C
1 1 12 4
2 2  2 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `unstack`

```
> unstack(rev(dataframe_1))
  A  B C
1 1 12 4
2 2  2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

One option IF the number of elements in each group is constant.

```
data.frame(do.call(cbind, split(dataframe_1$b, dataframe_1$a)))

  A  B C
1 1 12 4
2 2  2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be also be done with `dcast` and `rowid` from `data.table`:

```
dcast(as.data.table(dataframe_1), rowid(a) ~ a, value.var = 'b')[, -1]
   A  B C
1: 1 12 4
2: 2  2 5
```

Here, `[, -1]` removes the first column (which is `rowid(a)`).